# Implementing UITextFieldDelegate in a separate class

Tags: ios, swift

I want to implement `UITextFieldDelegate` in a class separate from the `UIViewController` but when I do I get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception at runtime.

So why does this work:

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
{
  ...

  func createUI()
  {
    let someTextField: UITextField = UITextField()
    someTextField.delegate = self

    ...
  }

  func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool
  {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true;
  }
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController
{
  ...

  func createUI()
  {
    let someTextField: UITextField = UITextField()
    someTextField.delegate = MyTextFieldDelegate()

    ...
  }
}

class MyTextFieldDelegate : NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate
{
  func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool
  {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try putting the newly created delegate in a "strong" class variable. It's possible that the "assign" property of the delegate field is causing it to get deallocated right after it gets created.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note the declaration of `delegate`:

```
unowned(unsafe) var delegate: UITextFieldDelegate?
```

`MyTextFieldDelegate()` is created, assigned to `delegate`, and then deallocated when `createUI()` returns. It is deallocated by ARC because nothing owns it. The problem you are experiencing is exactly what `unsafe` is warning you about.

You need to create a strong reference to your `MyTextFieldDelegate` instance. You also need to guarantee that the delegate is not deallocated until after the text field is deallocated.

> Note the difference between this behavior and `weak`. If the delegate were `weak` instead of `unowned(unsafe)`, then it would become `nil` and never get called, instead of crashing when it's called.

Comment: Thanks for that, all my years of Java have made me take memory management for granted...