# Create UITextField in different class doesn't allow to type

Tags: swift, uitextfield, swift4

I have this function in a separated class:

```
public static func TextField(x:CGFloat=0, y:CGFloat=0, width: CGFloat=0, height: CGFloat=0, placeholder: String="", fontSize:CGFloat=15, fontColor: UIColor=UIColor.black, fontWeight:UIFont.Weight=UIFont.Weight.light ,passwordField: Bool = false) -> UITextField{
        weak var delegate: UITextFieldDelegate?

        let textfield =  UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height))
        textfield.placeholder = placeholder
        textfield.textColor = fontColor
        textfield.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize, weight: fontWeight)
        textfield.isSecureTextEntry = passwordField
        textfield.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        textfield.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.no
        textfield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default
        textfield.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignment.center
        textfield.delegate = delegate
        return textfield
    }
```

And it's creating the `UITextField` correctly, with the right behavior that I expected, I cant't type of any of the `UITextFields`.

Also, I tried adding a separate class like this:

```
class MyTextFieldDelegate : NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate{
  func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool{
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true;
  }
}
```

But is not working.
Also, reading an [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032973/implementing-uitextfielddelegate-in-a-separate-class)

```
unowned(unsafe) var delegate: UITextFieldDelegate?
```

returns the error:

> 'unowned' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types,
>   not 'UITextFieldDelegate?'

How I can't make write on my `UITextfield` ?

Comment: Surely you're just setting the delegate to nil? I thought you had to set the text field delegate to a vc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a static let variable with a strong reference to use it in your factory function (follow Swift name convention and call it for example makeDefaultTextField), and just to make it clearer when you assign the delegate you are giving the responsibility to manage the delegate methods to your class:

```
static let myDelegate = MyTextFieldDelegate()

public static func makeDefaultTextField(x:CGFloat=0, y:CGFloat=0, width: CGFloat=0, height: CGFloat=0, placeholder: String="", fontSize:CGFloat=15, fontColor: UIColor=UIColor.black, fontWeight:UIFont.Weight=UIFont.Weight.light ,passwordField: Bool = false) -> UITextField {
    let textfield =  UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height))
    //....
    textField.delegate = myDelegate
}
```

If you want to manage the delegate methods in your ViewController(highly suggested) you can do it in this way, for example:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let txtField = YourClass.makeDefaultTextField()
        txtField.delegate = self
    }
}

extension YourViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    //call here the methods 
}
```